# MySQL installation on centOS fails - dependency issues

Tags: linux, centos, mysql, yum

I tried to install mysql on centOS following this [digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-centos-7) guide.

I ran the following commands;

```
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql80-community-release-el7-3.noarch.rpm
md5sum mysql80-community-release-el7-3.noarch.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh mysql80-community-release-el7-3.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install mysql-server
```

The first 3 commands execute successfully. However, the installation fails with a lot of dependency issues. I have gone through a lot of similar problems online, including this platform, but I've had no luck with solving mine.

**SOME MORE CONTEXT**

1: The output for `uname -r`

> 3.10.0-1127.19.1.el7.x86_64

2: The output for `sudo yum install mysql-server`

> Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.22-1.el8.x86_64
> (mysql80-community)
> Requires: libssl.so.1.1()(64bit) Error: Package: mysql-community-client-8.0.22-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
> Requires: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit) Error: Package: mysql-community-client-8.0.22-1.el8.x86_64
> (mysql80-community)
> Requires: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_1)(64bit) Error: Package: mysql-community-client-8.0.22-1.el8.x86_64
> (mysql80-community)
> Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit) Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.22-1.el8.x86_64
> (mysql80-community)
> Requires: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.11)(64bit) Error: Package: mysql-community-client-plugins-8.0.22-1.el8.x86_64
> (mysql80-community)
> Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit) Error: Package: mysql-community-client-8.0.22-1.el8.x86_64
> (mysql80-community)
> Requires: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit) Error: Package: mysql-community-libs-8.0.22-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
> Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit)

> **BLAH BLAH BLAH**

> Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.22-1.el8.x86_64
> (mysql80-community)
> Requires: libtirpc.so.3(TIRPC_0.3.3)(64bit)  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem  You could try running:
> rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

3: I mistakenly tried to install the el8 version at first. When I realized I had made a mistake, I did this;

```
sudo yum remove mysql80-community-release-el8-1.noarch
yum clean all
```

after which I confirmed that the old packages were gone;

`yum list | grep mysql`

> akonadi-mysql.x86_64           1.9.2-4.el7         base
>
> apr-util-mysql.x86_64          1.5.2-6.el7         base
>
> dovecot-mysql.x86_64           1:2.2.36-6.el7_8.1  updates
>
> freeradius-mysql.x86_64        3.0.13-10.el7_6     base
>
> libdbi-dbd-mysql.x86_64        0.8.3-16.el7        base
>
> mysql-connector-java.noarch    1:5.1.25-3.el7      base
>
> mysql-connector-odbc.x86_64    5.2.5-8.el7         base
>
> pcp-pmda-mysql.x86_64          4.3.2-7.el7_8       updates
>
> php-mysql.x86_64               5.4.16-48.el7       base
>
> php-mysqlnd.x86_64             5.4.16-48.el7       base
>
> qt-mysql.i686                  1:4.8.7-8.el7       base
>
> qt-mysql.x86_64                1:4.8.7-8.el7       base
>
> qt5-qtbase-mysql.i686          5.9.7-2.el7         base
>
> qt5-qtbase-mysql.x86_64        5.9.7-2.el7         base
>
> redland-mysql.x86_64           1.0.16-6.el7        base
>
> rsyslog-mysql.x86_64           8.24.0-52.el7_8.2   updates

```
yum repolist
```

> Loaded plugins: fastestmirror Loading mirror speeds from cached
> hostfile  * base: uk.mirrors.clouvider.net  * extras:
> mirrors.ukfast.co.uk  * updates: mirrors.ukfast.co.uk repo id
> repo name
> status base/7/x86_64
> CentOS-7 - Base
> 10,070 extras/7/x86_64
> CentOS-7 - Extras
> 413 updates/7/x86_64
> CentOS-7 - Updates
> 1,134 repolist: 11,617

I have no idea why I still can't install mysql, even after getting rid of the wrong package and clearing cache. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed all yum cache manually, then ran the installation again. It worked fine.

```
sudo rm -r /var/cache/yum/*
```

Comment: It sounds like Michael's answer fixed your issue. Please accept the answer to give him credit and let others know that the problem has been solved.

Comment: @CatherineMacInnes I upvoted Michael's answer. However, I'm still new to ServerFault, so my upvote doesn't change the publicly displayed score. I appreciate he took his time to provide a solution, I really do. However, his solution just didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

You still need to clean out the metadata from the inappropriate yum repo you had installed.

```
yum clean metadata
```

After this, you should be able to install packages.

Comment: **Here's the output**

`10 metadata files removed 6 sqlite files removed 0 metadata files removed`

**However, I still get the same error when trying to reinstall**